# didn't use to vs used not to

Tags: grammar

In all the coursebooks I've used there has not been a mention of the structure *used not to* in a sense that somebody did not do something for some time but started doing it. Consider the following examples:

1. He didn't use to do a lot of experiments.
2. He used not to do a lot of experiments.

Is example (2) grammatical and/or acceptable? If so, is there any pragmatic difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: It's only relevant to the *written* form, because normally it's not possible to differentiate in speech, but I'd rather write *He didn't **used** to do a lot of experiments.* Having said that, I double there's universal agreement between grammarians / pedants on that score. Note that the contraction in example #1 is perfectly natural, but contracted *He **usen't** to do that* would generally be seen as an "affectation". Also note that the negation can be shifted closer to the infinitive: 2a *He used to **not do** that.*

Comment: Yes: it's grammatical, but acceptability is another matter. Syntactically, this "use" is a lexical verb in 1. and an auxiliary verb in 2., the latter belonging to a somewhat more formal style and only marginally acceptable to most speakers. Younger speakers in particular, I believe, reject its auxiliary use altogether.

Comment: They both mean the same thing, but #2 is unidiomatic in American English; you will virtually never hear it.